# Can Express.js have a race condition on post

Tags: node.js, express, race-condition

Node noob question here I'm sure.

I have the below code in a simple express JS app

```
var randomPin = require('./api/randomPin');
var currentPin = "pin";
app.post('/match', function(req, res) { 
    if (req.body.pin && req.body.pin == currentPin) {
            //it should only be possible for one person to get here
            //and receive this hurrah
        currentPin = randomPin.generate();
        res.send({hurrah:true});
    }

    res.send({hurrah:false});
});
```

I'm still don't grok the workflow of a Node request...

Is it possible for a race condition to arise where two post requests to `/match` are being processed at the same time such that both posts are trying to call `randomPin.generate()`?

If so is there a 'best way' of avoiding this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are two POST `/match` requests, second request will wait until the first request is completed. However, if your post handler updates any global variables or object (e.g. cache), that change will be visible to other requests.

In your case `randomPin.generate()` will not have a *race condition* problem as there is no such thing as **simultaneous** execution in Node.js.

You can read more on that here: [Single threaded and Event Loop in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580048/single-threaded-and-event-loop-in-node-js)

Comment: so if randomPin.generate() went off and did async stuff to get its value then the second call to /match would potentially process before that returned?

Comment: if `randomPin.generate()` fires asynchronous code, then your current code will break because it expects a synchronous return value.  So, you'd have to create a queue that only allowed the next call to complete once `randomPin.generate()` finished its work.

Comment: @Jason, that's a very good point. However, as `randomPin.generate()` was used in synchronous way in the question, I assumed it work that way, similar to `crypto.randomBytes()` (which can also accept callback function).

Comment: @Tom I made the same assumption, I was just trying to provide more context for Paul's follow up question.

Comment: Thanks both... that's all a bit clearer to me now. As I opened up with I still don't grok what's happening under the hood :)

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood correctly, here's some info that might help you figure out what you're trying to figure out:

Node is single threaded.  That means that every request that comes in will be handled serially.  Let's say user 1 requests `/match` and sends `pin=pin`, and user 2 requests `/match` with `pin=pin` at the exact same millisecond.  When your node server receives these two requests, it will trigger an event for each... ***but it won't trigger those events in parallel, because node is single threaded.***  One event will fire first, and then the next.  The first event to fire will complete its callback, and will run `randomPin.generate()`.  Once it's finished, then the next event will run its callback, and `currentPin` will be set to the new value.

Comment: Hi @Jason, can you check this question of mine, its similar to this one but I haven't gotten the exact answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244580/is-there-any-race-condition-below/