# Is there any race condition below?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, race-condition

I have below code in my express server (have cut it down for brevity). I have a common object which I'm adding/modifying/reading in three different restful end points. Since all http requests in nodejs are asynchronous, I could get both put and get request *at the same time*. So although PUT happened but lets say status is *not* updated, my GET could get a slightly stale response?

From what I understand, and my testing shows that there is no race condition here. Because updating `results` object is a synchronous operation and all async operations should wait for it. Can somebody help with a better explanation whether this is correct or not?

```
    var obj = {};
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    app.post('/foo', (req, res) => {
         var result = {};
         result.id = generateSomeRandomId();
         result.failed = 0;
         result.status = 'running'
         //execute some command and update result
         const child = exec('some command');
         child.stdout.on('data',  (data) => {
             //some logic
         });
         child.stderr.on('data',  (data) => {
             result.failed = result.failed + 1;
          });
         child.on('close',  (code, signal) => {
              if (signal !== null && signal !== undefined) {
                    result.status = 'cancelled';
              } else {
                    result.status = 'completed';
                    result.runtime = calculateRunTime();
                }
         });
         result.pid = child.pid;
         obj[result.id] = result; 
         res.send(result); 
    }   

    app.put('/foo/:id', (req, res) => {
         var result =  obj[req.params.id];
         if (result.status === 'running' && result.pid !== undefined) {
              kill(result.pid, 'SIGKILL');
              result.status = 'cancelled';
              result.runtime = calculateRunTime();
         }
         res.send(result);
    }   
    app.get('/foo/:id', (req, res) => {
         var result =  obj[req.params.id];
         res.send(result);
    }
```

Comment: are you talking about in `app.post('/foo'`? there's no "race", but you will `res.post(result);` before any of the asynchronous parts even run ... so, whatever you do between `//execute some command and update result` and `result.pid = child.pid;` will have no effect on what you send in `res.send(result);`

Comment: also, `result.failed = result.failed + 1;` results in either `results.failed` being `undefined` or, if any errors, `result.failed === NaN`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I get that part. All async operations in *post* will wait until all sync operations complete. My question was mostly on concurrent PUT and GET requests. Would I have race condition there. And you are right about the result.failed `NaN` part, I skipped the initialization for brevity. Will add it back.

Comment: I just re-read the code ... I see what you're doing, so, you're starting "some command" and then polling for a result

Comment: @JaromandaX can you let me know what you think about the race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything I would call a "race condition"; there is an element of uncertainty at play here, but in practice it's not likely to matter.

It looks like your `post` starts a process and returns the ID, your `put` cancels the process, and your `get` returns the current state of the process. From this I gather that you'll never be able to `get` until your `post` completes and provides the ID.

If you make a `get` call that is received and returned before your `exec` asynchronous listeners complete​, you'll get whatever the last in-progress state is - I assume that's by design. So the only possible conflict here is if you've made a `put` call to halt your process.

Both your `put` and your `get` are synchronous when it comes to interacting with your result object, so whichever one is received first is the one that will complete first. You can ignore the process cancellation request for our purposes because it doesn't modify the result object. There's no guarantee that they will be received in the same order they were sent by the client(s), that may or may not be a practical concern in your scenario.

I *believe* (though my memory may be faulty here), that if you were using `cluster` to handle requests in different processes, you wouldn't be able to pass data around via a shared object anyway, so any complexity added by that possibility is already ruled out.

So, variances in network performance and reliability are your only real wildcard here. The server will handle requests in the order they come in and give you the expected results. If you only have a single client, you can wait until you get the response from your previous request to send the next one, which would potentially slow down your performance unacceptably, but make it more or less bulletproof. Otherwise, just send off your requests and don't worry about it, just make your app robust enough to recognize & handle a 2nd cancellation request even if you've already cancelled the process.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this makes sense. There is no race condition between POST and GET like you said, whatever the current state of the object is what GET will return. Now the question comes for POST and PUT at the same time, if POST is "almost" done (just came inside `child.on('close')`) and PUT comes at the same time, I might end up cancelling the process, although it has legitimately finished the execution. Would promises better served to avoid this?

Comment: I can't answer that without understanding your requirements - is there an "invalid" time to cancel a process? If so, that condition needs to be tracked in your result object and you need to check it and optionally "fail" to cancel - you could accomplish this by changing `result.status = 'finishing'` as soon as `child.on('close')` fires, which would cause it to fail your `result.status == 'running'` check in your put. If there's *not* an invalid time to cancel a process, then you've got to just accept that it's possible to cancel even if it's legitimately finished.

Comment: Oh, but also, there's still no "race condition" because your `on('close')` event and your `put` call are still executing in the same process - if the `close` call happens first, then it'll complete first, if the `put` call happens first, it'll complete first. So, that makes my first comment irrelevant.

Comment: But isn't `on('close')` happening in a asynchronous callback? So If I understand you right, if `on('close')` came first, it would finish first before executing PUT? But other thing to note that is everything in PUT is synchronous

Comment: This is the part of javascript asynchronicity that everyone misunderstands. `on('close')` is an asynchronous event listener.  But when it fires, it runs the callback in your one main thread.  Just like your `put()` is an asynchronous event listener, but when it fires, it runs the callback in your one main thread. So, whichever event fires first is the one that completes first - they will never run in parallel (again, making the assumption that your code won't work with `cluster` as-is anyway, so you don't have to worry about any sort of multi-processing).

Answer (score 1):

It's just an idea, but maybe a Promise could be helpful here:

```
var obj = {};
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
app.post('/foo', (req, res) => {
     var result = {};
     result.id = generateSomeRandomId();
     result.status = 'running';
     const child = exec('some command');
     child.stdout.on('data',  (data) => {
         //some logic
     });

     result.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
       child.stderr.on('data',  (data) => {
           result.failed = result.failed + 1;
           resolve(false);
        });
       child.on('close',  (code, signal) => {
            // ...
           resolve(true);
       });
     });

     result.pid = child.pid;
     obj[result.id] = result;
     res.send(result); 
}   

app.get('/foo/:id', (req, res) => {
     var result =  obj[req.params.id];
     if(result.status === 'running') {
       result.promise.then(() => res.send(result));
     }
     else {
       res.send(result);
     }
}
```

In this case GET would respond only when the `child` is done by error or 'close' event.

Comment: +1, thanks. Using promises is an interesting idea. My requirement is that even when the child process is running, I need to return the current result, so I don't want to wait until the child process is complete. Also I have a PUT which also modifies results.

Comment: Also in this solution GET if child is not done, what happens? client waits?

Comment: @Manali Yes, it will wait.

Comment: you think there is a race condition in the original code? Can you explain that part?

Comment: @Manali Yes, I think there may be some kind of race conditions. For example you send 2 requests, PUT and GET, one by one. And you are expecting that PUT will kill the process and GET will get you 'cancelled' status. But during sending these requests over the network the order of packages might be changed, and GET might come before PUT (also, PUT request could be lost at all). And you will get irrelevant picture.